# Amazon listing create is getting failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

i am trying to create amazon listing with put
PUT https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/AXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ABC123

API and my final json is

i am posting for personal computer category

```
{"productType":"PERSONAL_COMPUTER","requirements":"LISTING","attributes":{"processor_count":[{"value":4,"marketplace_id":"testID"}],"fcc_radio_frequency_emission_compliance":[{"identification_number":"2AZDM-BTWIFI","registration_status":"has_fcc_id","marketplace_id":"TEstID"}],"resolution":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"1920 x 1080","marketplace_id":"TEstID"}],"model_name":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Dell XPS 8930  Desktop I7","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"bullet_point":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"POWERFUL PROCESSOR - Configured with Intel’s top of the line Core i5 series processor so you can expect very fast, reliable and consistent performance for an exceptional PC experience.","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"product_description":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Dell XPS 8930  Desktop I7","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"brand":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Dell","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"generic_keyword":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Personal Computer","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"hardware_platform":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"PC","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"total_usb_2_0_ports":[{"value":2,"marketplace_id":"ID"}],"item_type_keyword":[{"value":"tower-computers","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"warranty_description":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"90 days warranty","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"hard_disk":[{"size":[{"unit":"GB","value":120.0}],"description":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"SSD+HDD"}],"interface":[{"value":"pci_express_x2"}],"marketplace_id":"ID"}],"color":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Black","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"manufacturer":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Intel"}],"system_ram_type":[{"value":"ddr_sdram","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"operating_system":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Windows 10 Pro","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"model_number":[{"value":"OptiPlex","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"externally_assigned_product_identifier":[{"value":"885909859054","type":"UPC"}],"wireless_communication_technology":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Bluetooth","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"item_name":[{"language_tag":"en_US","value":"Dell XPS 8930  Desktop I7","marketplace_id":"ID"}],"main_Product_Image_Locator":[{"marketplace_id":"ID","media_location":"C:\\Users\\dell\\source\\repos\\Latest Main Repo\\AmazonReceiptReporting\\images\\test112233-0307b1fd-9866-4ee1-8645-b995ef30b1c4.jpg"}],"list_price":[{"marketplace_id":"ID","currency":"USD","value":699.0}],"country_of_origin":[{"marketplace_id":"ID","value":"US"}]}}

but still getting error {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

}
}
The Canonical String for this request should have been

all my credentials are correct as i am able to call other amazon APIs with same so its basically something wrong with my payload. CAn anyone suggest what is wrong?